# jquery - make page post back to itself but adding get parameters from variables to the url

Tags: php, jquery

How to make a page reload itself with get parameters that have been passed into variables in jQuery.

So in the `onclick` function of a button something like

```
var myget = "<?php echo $customer_id ?>";
```

Now post back to page with this get string.

Comment: Get rid of jQuery, do a normal post followed by a `header` redirect in php.

Comment: It will be like: `window.location.href=""+document.URL+""+myget+"";`
But when `onwhichEvent?` you want to change the URL??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You code is like this:

```
echo<<<HTML
<element onclick='var myget="<?php echo $customer_id ?>";' />
HTML;
```

You just need to change it like this:

```
echo<<<HTML
<element onclick='var myget="<?php echo $customer_id ?>;window.location.href=""+document.URL+""+myget+"";' />
HTML;
```

and that's it.

if your element is an `<a>` tag then might need to use `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault();`.

Hope it'll help you.